# How to set an integer above and below two numbers in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, I need to know how to set all integers in a single column to be 10 if the value is above or equal to 10 and below  or equal to 30.

I figured this would work, but it did not.

```
UPDATE testtable1 SET value1 =10 WHERE value1 >=10 AND value1 <=30;
```

Comment: How did it "_not work_"? Did you had an unexpected result, an error, did it not do anything?

Comment: When I tried it, nothing happened. I used the correct names for everything, and no the table is actually called testtable1 because I am just testing something.

Comment: @GNCode How did you run the query? Maybe you have have a transaction and did not commit it.

Comment: SO is a great site to ask questions and get answers: Just be sure to provide a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Before you ask a question consider [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Yes, I'm serious! To help us help you, generate sample data and expected results. [ascii table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) makes the output easy to read! You could also mock up data and the SQL tried using http://rextester.com/ or a similar site.  Pretty much anything is possible; it's a matter of should we do it; not can we.

Comment: What is the DDL for testtable?  is value1 numeric? or is implicit casting going on and potentially causing an error?  Seems to work in this demo: http://rextester.com/PXTV56541

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks correct just pay attention that you've replaced `table` with your real table name and `value` with your real column name. Query must looks like:

```
UPDATE {yourTableName} SET {yourFieldName} = 10
WHERE {yourFieldName} >= 10 AND {yourFieldName} <= 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`UPDATE testtable1 SET value1 =10 WHERE value1 >=10 AND value1 <=30;`

You could do 

`UPDATE testtable1 SET value1 =10 WHERE value1 BETWEEN 10 AND 30;`

other example:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question. this may help

```
UPDATE testtable1 SET value1 =10 WHERE value1 >=10 Or value1 <=30;
```